# How to get NBA 2K13 working

Tags: installation, games

I am confused about how certain games can or can not be played on Ubuntu. Every sort of "Big Market" game available is not supported on Linux. However, when looking on Amazon, I stumbled across NBA 2K13 in the Linux Games section. Here is the link: [http://www.amazon.com/NBA-2K13-windows-linux-PCLinux-Unix/dp/B007MMINWQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007MMINWQ)

My question is, if I buy this game, can I just pop it in and it will give me installation instructions and then I can play, just like on Windows 7? Or will I have to do it some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I believe that game is really supported directly under Linux at all.  Short of seeing something on the actual BOX ITSELF saying so, I would tend to assume this is probably miscategorized on Amazon.

I did some searching and was unable to find any website talking about a native Linux port of the game, only people talking about (successfully) getting it running under Wine.  So, probably a miscategorization.  You could ask Amazon support about this if you're really feeling hopeful, and maybe see if you could get somebody there to either actually read the box or guarantee a refund should you get it and find out that it's simply been miscategorized.  That's the best advice I've got for you.

**Btw:** check out http://humblebundle.com/ for a fair number of pretty cool indie games that **are** directly supported on Linux and easy to install - most of them can even install directly from the Software Center, once you've purchased your Bundle!

Comment: Thanks! yes, I know about the Humble Bundle. I actually don't have Ubuntu yet though, I just bought some parts to build my first computer and am going to have Ubuntu on that as my operating system. I should have it up by next week and I'm excited!

Comment: Excellent!  Welcome to the community; I hope you enjoy Ubuntu as much as I do. =)